# Using tuples has keys in Julia without initializing the dictionary

Tags: dictionary, julia

I am new to Julia.  For my application I have an expensive operation to calculate a matrix based on two points.  Calculated matrices will be used multiple times so I though I would cache them in a dictionary.  However, I have encountered a strange behaviour in Julia.  If I add a first (key, value) pair as part of the dictionary initialization it all works as expected.  However, if I don't, and try and add my first (key, value) pair later, Julia bombs out.

```
p1 = [ 2.0, 1.0, 1.0]
p2 = [ 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]

# This works
my_dict = Dict{Tuple{Array{Float64,1}, Array{Float64,1}}, String}(
    (p1, p2) => "hello world"
)
println(my_dict[(p1, p2)])

# This works
my_dict[ (p2, p1)] = "hello again"
println(my_dict[ (p2, p1)] )

# This doesn't
my_dict2 = Dict{Tuple{Array{Float64,1}, Array{Float64,1}}, String}
my_dict2[(p2, p1)] = "this fails with method dispatch error"
```

Output from Julia:

```
julia complex_key_for_dict.jl 
hello world
hello again
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::Type{Dict{Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}},String}}, ::String, ::Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}})
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [5] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:267
 [6] _start() at ./client.jl:436
in expression starting at /home/peter/julia/gps_analysis/complex_key_for_dict.jl:16
```

For now, I will simply add a fictitious first entry into the dictionary, but would be grateful if someone can put me straight on my error.

Comment: Just in case you don't know it, it's not necessary to include the complicated type signature if you are instantiating the dict with values. Just write: `d = Dict((p1, p2) => "Hello world!")`, and the correct type is automatically inferred. You only have to specify the type if you want a more permissive signature.

Comment: That is useful, and I didn't know that.  In my real app (as opposed to this toy version) I will be defining the cache ahead of time so will need the signature for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing like posting a question to StackOverflow to me make realise what the solution might be.  This works:

```
# This works.  Added an open/close bracket to the end of the Dict defintion
my_dict2 = Dict{Tuple{Array{Float64,1}, Array{Float64,1}}, String}()
my_dict2[ (p2, p1)] = "this now works"

println(my_dict2[ (p2, p1)])
```

Thought I would post the answer so that anyone else who has also banged their head against a brick wall on this may find it helpful.